# ASP MVC 3 - Submit Ajax.BeginForm from Javascript

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a few ajax forms dotted around my view, and I want one main submit which would submit all other ajax forms.

Is there any recommended way to do this via javascript? (i.e $("myForm).submit();)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the normal $("#myForm").submit(); like detailed in my post, that does it for me.